# Powershell remote session hangs after trying to unzip a file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, unzip, invoke-command

I have a Powershell remote session that unzips a downloaded file.

There is a problem though. Every time I unzip the file using -Com Shell.Application object, my remote session freezes, and a wsmprovhost.exe process gets stuck on the target server. It actually unzips the file and then hangs.

The simplified version of the code is represented below, assuming a proper PSCredential object has been created.

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName MyHost -Credential $credentials
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { 
    $webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $webClient.DownloadFile("http://somesite.com/some_path/config.zip", "C:\Temp\config.zip")
    $shellApp = New-Object -Com Shell.Application
    $zipFile = $shellApp.namespace("C:\Temp\config.zip")
    $destination = $shellApp.namespace("C:\Temp")
    $destination.CopyHere($zipFile.items(), 1564)
} -Session $session
Remove-PSSession -Session $session
```

Of course, the unzipping is a crucial part of this remotely executed script, but all the rest work fine if the unzip part is removed, including some other commands that should be executed after the unzip (and were omitted for the sake of brevity).

Does anyone have any idea why the execution freezes after the zip file is exploded?

Comment: I would recommend not trying to automate zip files using `Shell.Application` as that is intended to be used interactively.

Comment: Actually I am trying to unzip them. But the problem is the target servers are running Powershell v2 and I cannot install .NET 4.5, which leaves me basically without options.

Comment: By 'automate zip files using `Shell.Application`' I meant 'handle zip files in any way (zip or unzip) using `Shell.Application`'. My comment still stands. I'm not surprised it doesn't work. The `Shell.Application` objects are generally designed for interactive use, not automation in a script.

Comment: I got it, but if you are stuck with an older .NET version, what other options are left?

Comment: Use a command-line executable instead.

Comment: [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)

Comment: Yes, or the Info-Zip tools.

Comment: Well guys, thanks for the suggestions but unfortunately the solutions presented would be a huge overkill for this automation that was trying to be done. Those servers are barebones and I am not allowed to install anything on them.

As a workaround solution, I am unzipping the file in the agent folder where I am running the script using Shell.Application locally, and copying the files to the target servers using Copy-Item and PSDrive.

Comment: There is no install needed for `zip.exe` and `unzip.exe`. They are standalone executables. Just copy the files onto the computer and run them.